# Symfony's make:entity fails to determine locate for new class despite passing full namespace

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I am using Symfony 3.4 and I have the `src/AppBundle`.

I tried to add new entity with `bin/console make:entity`, but it fails to create it.

No matter if I provide `MyClass` or `\AppBundle\Entity\MyClass` or any other strange combination (`AppBundle\Entity\MyClass`, `App\Entity\MyClass`, `\AppBundle\MyClass`...) for class name, it always says:

> Could not determine where to locate the new class "App\Repository\Entity\MyClassRepository", maybe try with a full namespace like "\My\Full\Namespace\MyClassRepository"

Which looks to me that it ignored the `\AppBundle\Entity` (full namespace) I've already explicitly provided.

Also adding `maker.yaml` inside `app/config/package/dev` (as suggested in error message) has no effect on it.

Comment: Have you tried `\App\AppBundle\Entity\MyClass`?

Comment: Did you try to set `root_namespace` as said here https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html?

Comment: @qdequippe Yes, inside `maker.yaml`, with no effect.